# AngularJS does it cache and is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angularjs-scope

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/template/edit-modal.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl2,
    resolve: {
        locations: function () {
            return locationToEdit;
        }
    },
    scope: $scope.$new()
});
```

I have a handful of modal windows that open up using the above script. It works wonders, but what I'm noticing is that in some browsers the `templateUrl` is being cached by the browser and any changes done to the `html` file are only seen when the cache is cleared.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening as changes may happen to the modal at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing any cache busting technique.
Simplest one to not have any cache would be to add a redundant and changing GET parameter to the url :

```
templateUrl: '/template/edit-modal.html' + '?a=' + Math.random()
```

A better technique would  be to use "?version=" , where version would be some string decided by your system, such that version changes whenever your template changes.

Answer (score -1):

I got over this issue by using `$templateCache.removeAll();` in the application.